# Convert Object to Array or list

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i have an object  that is being passed to me from a json obj, each time it is has different feilds, i am using json.net to parse it, it is parsing it correctly and it is putting it in a list of obj

the format after serialization is:

```
{
    "language": "EN",
    "code": "test",
    "name": "test",
    "value": "TEST",
    "id": "2222222222222222"
}
```

the fields are dynamic it can be up to 50 not just 5

any idea on how to parse it??

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do which Json.NET isn't already doing for you...

Comment: no json.net is parsing it into an list of object which will not work for me

Comment: i have tried this :   string[] arr = ((IEnumerable)item.custom_fields).Cast<object>()
                                 .Select(x => x.ToString())
                                 .ToArray();

Answer (score 0):

If you know the items in above format. you could create an typed object. and then you can use [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) like below.

```
  DataContractJsonSerializer obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Student>));
    List<Student> result = obj.ReadObject(stream) as List<myClass>;
```

Comment: the idea that i dont know how many fields the service return it could be 1 or 100

Comment: do you have idea what all these fields could be. ?

Comment: key and value it depend on what the admin chooses